# How to filter array of timestamp in order to keep specific hours?

Tags: ios, swift, date

Imagine this array of timestamps `[Double]` :

```
hourlyTimes": [1551344400, 1551348000, 1551351600, 1551355200, 1551358800, 1551362400, 1551366000, 1551369600, 1551373200 ... ]
```

It corresponds to the hours for which I have data to display.

To keep it simple, here is the full array when I display only the hours (**UTC**) :

```
Hours = [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 0, 6, 12, 18, 0, 6, 12, 18, 0, 6, 12, 18, 0, 6, 12, 18, 0, 6, 12, 18, 0]
```

Now here is what I want to achieve, I need to filter this array of timestamp, in order to only keep these specific hours on any day (three-hourly).

```
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
```

---

Ok, now let's have a look at the **code** :

```
let arrayOfTimestamp = time.hourlyTimes
let arrayOfHours = arrayOfTimestamp.map({ Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: $0).hoursUTC})
let hoursToKeep = [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
let filtered = arrayOfHours.intersection(with: hoursToKeep)
```

---

**Some explanations here:**

`time` in the first line is the response from the backend, returning me all the available timestamps.

```
struct MultiForecastTimeModel: Codable {
    let hourlyTimes: [Double]
    let dailyTimes: [Double]
}
```

---

`.hoursUTC` is just a Date extension, in order to retrieve the hour component of the Date object.

```
var hoursUTC: Int {
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    let timezone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
    calendar.timeZone = timezone
    return calendar.component(.hour,  from: self)
}
```

---

And finally, `.intersection` is an extension too, in order to do the same as a classic `intersection`, but also keeping the index and the occurrences.

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {

    func intersection(with filter: [Element]) -> [Element] {
        return self.filter { element in filter.contains(element) }
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine, my only issue is that I now have to associate all these values as an Array of tuples.

Like this :

```
let tuples = Array(zip(filtered, filtered.dropFirst()))
```

But with an actual timestamp (corresponding to real date), not just an array of Int (hour component).

Because in the end, here what I have to do :

```
self.hourlyMapDataSource.data.value = tuples
```

and my datasource is expecting a tuple of timestamp `(Double, Double)`

```
class HourlyMapDataSource : GenericDataSource<(Double, Double)>, UICollectionViewDataSource { }
```

Do you have any pieces of advice on how should I improve my code and/or my logic?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** My tuple array should only contain timestamps whose time has been "validated" through the `hoursToKeep` array so that it has 3 hours difference between hours.

I will show you with the hours to keep it simple, but it's an actual corresponding timestamp that I want :

```
[(9, 12), (12, 15), (15, 18) ...]
```

Comment: what will your tuple have? (timestamp, kept hour)?

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tupleArray = hourlyTimes.map { (time: $0, hour: Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: $0).hoursUTC)}
```

Now you can run the reduce function on this

```
var selectedHours = tupleArray.filter { return hoursToKeep.contains($0.hour) }
```

This will give you an array of tuples which have the validated hours,

```
[(1551344400, 9), (1551348000, 12)]
```

Comment: Should'nt you use `filter` instead of reduce in order to have an Array as output ?

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo Thank you for pointing that out mate. corrected. Cheers.

Comment: The creation of the Tuple with timestamp and hour associated directly in the .map is brillant. I didn't think about it. I overthought this...

Comment: @Balanced Happy to have helped mate. Your question was well put which itself guided me to this solution. Cheers.

Comment: I tried to explain the problem as clearly as I could. Because the problem is not often the code, but the explanation.